# Create stubbed out class with Visual Studio

Tags: .net, wsdl

I'm working in Visual Studio 2013 and have a WSDL.  I've added it as a Web Reference and need to create a stubbed out class from this web reference in my project but can't for the life of me figure out where/how I'm supposed to do this.

Comment: First of all, you should add it as a Service Reference, not a web reference. Second, exactly what do you mean a stubbed-out class? Exactly what do you want to do with that class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm new to .NET, I'm a Java guy :)

What I mean by a stubbed out class is, I want VS to read the WSDL and create a class for me with all of the available methods.  I don't care they are blank, I just don't want to write out 60 some odd methods just to get started.

Comment: You don't have to. Just use "Add Service Reference".

Comment: See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)" to see how this works in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Web references are added for .Net version 2.0 and below.  If that is your intent, please follow the instructions found at [Web Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649(v=vs.120).aspx)

if you are targeting version 2.0 and above, please follow the instructions found at [Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx)

Once you have a reference created in your project, a file called "Reference.cs" gets created.  It is located under ..PathToProject\Service References\Reference Name

The reference file contains the stubbed out class you are looking for.  Just create and instance of the class and begin using it's methods.

By the way, the reference.cs file is hidden by default.  To view it in your solution explorer just click on the "show all files" button.